# Setting # of decimal places in case statement with trailing zero

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, decimal, case

In SQL Server 2008 I am trying to get results to truncate to a specific number of decimal places depending on the value of the field.  The trouble I am running into is if the last decimal place is going to be zero then it doesn't display it.  My code is as follows:

`case when @field >= 250 then round(@field,1,1)
     when @field between 100 and 249.9999 then round(@field,2,1)
     when @field < 100 then round(@field,3,2) end`

It works great by changing `250.36745` into `250.3`, but `250.04567` returns `250` and I need it to be `250.0`

Answer (score 0):

The result given back to you depends on the original data type for @field. I'd assume that you haven't chosen a precise data type (example: float) for @field and therefore get a variable result back. If you want a precise result back then you can do so by wrapping your case statement into a cast like so:

```
cast(case when @field >= 250 then round(@field, 1, 1)
          when @field between 100 and 249.9999
          then round(@field, 2, 1)
          when @field < 100 then round(@field, 3, 2)
     end as decimal(19, 1))
```

If you still feel that you allegedly get back `250` instead of `250.0` from the server then I'd question the front-end tool you are using to execute the query and to display the result. In SSMS you will certainly get back `250.0`. But if you are using a different client then the result may vary.